# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Comment without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On my Comment view page (show.html) I have a button that, when clicked, will create a row in a different table called Repost (it has a reposts_controller and a repost model). However, when I click on the icon on the Comment show page, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Comment without an ID
```

Here's the RepostsController:

```
class RepostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @repost = @comment.reposts.build(params[:comment])
  @repost.user = current_user
    if @repost.save
      #flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'activities'
    end
  end
end
```

I know what the problem is but I'm struggling with a solution. The CommentsController easily finds the comment to display on the show page. However, how do I send that id from the show page to the RepostsController so it can create the needed relationships shown above? It's a strange situation since the button is *on* the actual comment page but since the button writes a row to a different table using a different controller, the button can't see/find the comment.

Thanks!
-b

Added view:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag('star.png', :size => "16x16", :align => "right"), {:controller => 'reposts', :action => 'create', :id => @comment} %>
```

That link_to sends me to localhost/reposts?id=1 and nothing is created on the Reposts table.

Comment: Can we see the part of the view code where the link to this occurs? Are you passing `@comment` (or comment id) to the controller from the view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just added the view code. I was originally using a button in a form and that's what gave me the error. I tried a link_to from a different attempt and it just sends me to a blank page and no rows are created in the database.

Comment: What is the purpose of that link for the user? Is it to create a comment, or to create a repost?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. The link will need to create  a repost, but save the comment id and user I'd of the comment as foreign keys in the Repost table

Comment: To create something in the repost table, you need a `@repost = Repost.new(params[:repost])` as the first line within your `create`. You also need to replace `@repost = @comment.reposts...` with perhaps `@comment.reposts << @repost` but I need to see the association between comments and reposts from the models to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code ended up working:

```
class RepostsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @reposts = Repost.all
end

  def create
   @repost= Repost.new("comment_id" => params[:comment_id],"user_id" => params[:user_id])
   @content = @repost.comments.content
    if @repost.save
      #flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'activities'
    end

  end
end

<%= link_to image_tag('purple_star.png', :size => "16x16", :align => "right"), {:controller => 'reposts', :action => 'create', :comment_id => @comment, :user_id => @comment.user}, :title=> "Pass it on!", :method=>'post' %>
```

Thanks for the time and assistance everyone!